# I need just the Min

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, min

I have a query which needs to return the lowest balance for this month for each ID. The problem I am getting is it is returning multiple balances instead of the min balance on Balance.
I keep getting results like these:

```
ID      Name   Month     Year  TodayMonth   TodayYear  BalMin 
1        A      4         12     4            2012      10,000.00 
1        A      4         12     4            2012      20,000.00
```

When I need it to return just the lowest Balance:

```
ID      Name   Month     Year  TodayMonth   TodayYear  BalMin 
1        A      4         12     4            2012      10,000.00
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
     TOP (100) PERCENT History.ID, info.Name, DATEPART(mm, History.ReportDate) AS Month, DATEPART(yy,History.ReportDate) AS Year, DATEPART(mm, { fn CURDATE() }) AS TodayMonth, DATEPART(yy, { fn CURDATE() }) AS TodayYear, MIN(History.Balance) AS BalMin
    FROM         History LEFT OUTER JOIN Info ON History.ID = Info.ID
    WHERE     (DATEPART(yy, History.ReportDate) = DATEPART(yy, { fn CURDATE() })) AND (DATEPART(mm, History.ReportDate) = DATEPART(mm, 
                          { fn CURDATE() })) AND (History.Balance > 0)
    GROUP BY History.ID, History.ReportDate, Info.Name, History.Balance
    ORDER BY History.ID
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `group by` should not include balance (since you are running the min on it), and you should probably use the `datepart` that you are using in the select (otherwise you're not grouping by month).  The `left join` doesn't make sense either since you are looking for non-null records in your where clause anyway.  This might work:

```
SELECT History.ID,
    Info.Name,
    DATEPART(mm, History.ReportDate) AS [Month],
    DATEPART(yy, History.ReportDate) AS [Year],
    MIN(History.Balance) AS BalMin
FROM History
    JOIN Info ON History.ID = Info.ID
WHERE (DATEPART(yy, History.ReportDate) = DATEPART(yy, { fn CURDATE() }))
    AND (DATEPART(mm, History.ReportDate) = DATEPART(mm, { fn CURDATE() }))
    AND (History.Balance > 0)
GROUP BY History.ID,
    DATEPART(mm, History.ReportDate),
    DATEPART(yy, History.ReportDate),
    Info.Name
ORDER BY History.ID
```

I've also removed the `distinct` and `top` keywords, as you can see. `Distinct` is often unnecessary with `group by` (if not a code smell) and I'm assuming your `top` was for debugging or ordering a view, which you [should probably not do](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/11/24/sql-server-interesting-observation-top-100-percent-and-order-by/).

Comment: Glad to hear we nailed it the first time!

Comment: I've added a little more info that may be helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT
     TOP (100) PERCENT History.ID, info.Name, DATEPART(mm, History.ReportDate) AS Month, DATEPART(yy,History.ReportDate) AS Year, DATEPART(mm, { fn CURDATE() }) AS TodayMonth, DATEPART(yy, { fn CURDATE() }) AS TodayYear, MIN(History.Balance) AS BalMin
    FROM         History LEFT OUTER JOIN Info ON History.ID = Info.ID
    WHERE     (DATEPART(yy, History.ReportDate) = DATEPART(yy, { fn CURDATE() })) AND (DATEPART(mm, History.ReportDate) = DATEPART(mm, 
                          { fn CURDATE() })) AND (History.Balance > 0)
    GROUP BY History.ID, DATEPART(mm, History.ReportDate), Info.Name
    ORDER BY History.ID
```

I haven't inspected the rest of your query, but your GROUP BY is at least part of the problem. Take a look.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  i.*, minbalance
FROM    (
        SELECT  id, MIN(balance) AS minbalance
        FROM    history
        WHERE   reportDate >= DATEADD(day, -DAY(GETDATE()), CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))
                AND reportDate < DATEADD(month, 1, DATEADD(day, -DAY(GETDATE()), CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)))
                AND 
        GROUP BY
                id
        ) b
JOIN    info i
ON      i.id = h.id
```